# Ordering through has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have two types of records: Person and PersonDetail.

Each Person has_one PersonDetail.

I would like to order People based on a field that is in PersonDetail. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Person.joins(:person_detail).order('person_details.detail_field')
```